# Rails - NoMethodError in Events#show undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I'm building an Events app in Rails and getting this error which seems a little odd.

[image: Comments error]

It relates to the comments section at the foot of the show page. I'm simply attempting to move my comments form to the top of the section and have all recent comments below the form. This is my view code for the show page which results in the error code above -

```
 <div id="comments">

                        <h3>Add a comment:</h3>
                            <%= render "comments/form" %>   
                            <h2><%= @event.comments.count %></h2>
                            <%= render @event.comments %>       
                </div>
```

The reason I say its odd is that when I present the code like this (so the comments all show above the comment form) -

```
  <div id="comments">
                    <h2><%= @event.comments.count %></h2>
                            <%= render @event.comments %>       
                        <h3>Add a comment:</h3>
                            <%= render "comments/form" %>   
                </div>
```

I don't get the error code. Why would this be?

This is the code in my comments.html -

```
 <div class="comment clearfix">
<div class="comment_content">
    <p class="comment_name"><strong><%= comment.name %></strong></p>
    <p class="comment_body"><%= comment.body %></p>
    <p class="comment_time"><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> Ago</p>
</div>

<% if user_signed_in? %>
<p><%= link_to 'Delete', [comment.event, comment],
                              method: :delete,
                              class: "button",
                                data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></p>
<% end %>
```

The error refers to my events show action - I don't have any methods in my show action.

Comment: Nope, simply rearranging render calls should not make the error appear (or go away). Something else is going on.

Comment: So it is to do with the show action, then? I have an association between events & comments so do I need a method in the events_controller?

Comment: Any chance that your 'comments/form' instantiates a new comment by doing something like @event.comments.build?  If so, you're adding a new comment to the collection that the 'render @event.comments' collection is trying to display... and since that new comment has not been persisted, it's created_at is nil

Comment: So, this needs to go in the show action?

Comment: Since you want the last comment to appear first, are you somewhere checking whether created_at is > ? All records, even NIL should have created_at usually. Do you check something in your model or controller?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have a nested route to create comments and an un-nested route to destroy them:

```
resources :events do
  resources :comments, shallow: true, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

This is called *shallow nesting* and is desirable since it lets you route directly to resource for the member actions (show, edit, update, destroy) where a resource can be directly accessed through its unique id.

Then setup the form partial:

```
# comments/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for([commentable, Comment.new ]) do |f| %>

  # ... 
<% end %>
```

You then want to fix your `events/show` controller and view:

```
def show
  @event = Event.eager_load(:comments).find(params[:id])
end
```

Note that we are not building a comment instance in the controller. We will do it later in the form when needed.

```
<div id="comments">
   <% if @event.comments.any? %>
     <h2><%= @event.comments.size %></h2>
     <%= render @event.comments %>
   <% else %>
     <h2>There are no comments yet</h2>
   <% end %>
   <%= render 'comments/form', commentable: @event %>
</div>
```

Another big problem is that any signed in user can delete any comment. You can fix that by setting up an association:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
end
```

You then want to check that the user owns the comment:

```
<div class="comment clearfix">
  <div class="comment_content">
    <p class="comment_name"><strong><%= comment.name %></strong></p>
    <p class="comment_body"><%= comment.body %></p>
    <p class="comment_time"><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> Ago</p>
  </div>

  <% if user_signed_in? && comment.user == current_user %>
    <% button_to 'Delete', comment, 
       method: :delete, 
       class: "button", 
       data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } 
    %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Since we de-nested the destroy route you don't need to pass the event id as a param. Normally you want to use a library like Pundit or CanCanCan rather than spreading the authorization logic all over your application like this.

### Added

For the delete button to work you need to associate the user with the comment:

```
def create
  @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
  @comment = @event.comments.new(event_params) do |c|
    c.user = current_user
  end
  # ...
end
```

Comment: I understand all of this logic - and its required - however, it hasn't solved the original error. I still need to render my comments form to sit above the comments made and when I try and amend the views I get the error again.

Comment: Try using `form_for([commentable, Comment.new])` instead of `commentable.comments.new`.

Comment: It should work since you are not actually adding the the comment to the collection.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to add a route for the delete button as that's not showing on the page?

Comment: If you changed the routes like I suggested, than you should already have a delete route - `DELETE /comments/:id`. Run `bin/rake routes` to see your routes. If the button is not showing then it is because you are not associating the comment with the user. See my edit.

Comment: The link helpers and button helper would raise a error if the route could not be found.

Comment: Hmm, still nothing. You're right about the routes and no errors so I'm not drawing it out correctly. In the form I've ommitted the manual input of 'name' and I've tried comment.user in the html but still nothing showing. comment.current_user just brings a no method error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135776/discussion-between-max-and-mike-whitehead).